# Can landlord's business expenses be retroactive?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, rental-property, california, landlord

Say, I am planning on moving out of my house and keeping it as a rental. The house needs a bit of work, which I can start before I move out to save on the downtime before I look for renters. Can the expenses I thus incur still be deducted against rental income, and if yes, how far back can they go? I'm in California.

Comment: You might want to clarify what kind of work (are we talking painting the walls, or are we talking a new roof?) in case it's relevant.

Comment: Any "improvements" (versus repairs) while you have lived in the house will add to the basis (that you will depreciate as a rental expense).  Because of the 250K/500k capital gains exclusion, most private homeowners don't gain any value to track this.  With your conversion plan, you are no longer "most private homeowners".